# solve following regex

Tags: java, regex

Please consider the following text :

```
  String tempStr =
            "$#<div style=\"text-align:left;\">$#Order-CAS No#$</div>$#abc#$";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\$#)(\\w*)(?=#\\$)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(tempStr);

    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found a " + m.group() + ".");
```

but it give me just abc..i want answer as Order-CASNo and abc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `\\w*` does not match the hyphen or space. Try `[\\w\\s-]*` instead.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\$#)([\\w\\s-]*)(?=#\\$)");
```

Read more about character classes here:

- [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Thanks Mark..but if i write "Order-CAS No"...its not giving corrent answer.It does not support space.I am new to regex. So please tell to support space.

Comment: @rahul. Then add a space in the character class: - `[\\w\\s-]*`

Comment: @rahul, please do yourself a favor and read [a regex tutorial](www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). You can simply include any characters you want into the character group (into `[...]`). So just do `[\\w -]`. But I guess you will soon come up with more characters to match ;)

Comment: Could you explain why lookarounds instead of just matching by `\\$#[\\w\\s-]+#\\$`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got solution.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\$#)([\\w-\\s\\w]*)(?=#\\$)");
```

Comment: The second `\\w` in the character class does not do anything. Also, I recommend putting the `-` last in your character class. Otherwise you will get problems if you add single characters around it. Also be aware that `\\s` matches all whitespace, not just spaces (line breaks and tabs, too).